# how to dynamically add data from one html page to a list in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a list of string items on a html page, as follows-

```
<h1><b>Subject Groups</b></h1>
        <div id="listContainer">
            <div class="listControl">
            </div>
            <ul id="expList">
                <li>
                    Maths 
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            John Smith       
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Jane Smith
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Elvis Presley
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Science 
                    <ul>
                    <li>
                    Jane Smith
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    Kate Smith
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Literature
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Kate Smith
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Tom Hanks
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href = "JavaScript:newPopup('new.html');"<b>New Student..</b></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

At the end of the list, there is a link to a pop up form which allows you to input a new student and select via checkboxes what subjects that person is studying-

```
<form action="" style= "font-size: 16pt">

<h3> First Name: </h3>

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">

      <h3> Last Name: </h3>

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">


      <h3> Email Address: </h3>

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" size="70" class="form-control">

    </div><!-- /input-group -->

    <h3> Select the subjects that this student will study: </h3>


<input type="checkbox" name="Maths" value="Maths"> &nbsp Maths<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Science" value="Science"> &nbsp Science<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Literature" value="Literature"> &nbsp Literature>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My question is- how would I go about using the onClick event of the submit button to take the first name and last name of a newly created student and add them to the appropriate subject category in my list? Is that possible without having a database behind it?

Comment: this looks like a job for jQUery: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it will be easy to do with jquery...just give each subject an
>   a ID to like e.g `<li id="Maths">` then when user submits form get the
>   checkbox value and use .append to add to the list e.g.

```
> $(chekBoxValue).append("<li>"+name+'</li>');
```

hope this helps